# NEXTJS google trend API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, google-trends

Having trouble using the npm google trends api in NEXTJS

Not sure if this is the right way to go about it.

I made a new API route.

```
http://localhost:3000/api/trends
```

http://localhost:3000/api/trends

```
import googleTrendsApi from "google-trends-api";

const handler = async (res, req) => {
  const data = await googleTrendsApi
    .interestOverTime({ keyword: ["Women's march", "Trump Inauguration"] })
    .then(function (results) {
      console.log("These results are awesome", results);
    });

  res.status(200).json({ data: data });
};
```

I get an error saying

```
TypeError: res.status is not a function
```

Comment: The `handler`'s signature should be `(req, res)`, `res` is the second argument not the first - the order matters. `req.status` (from the first argument) doesn't exist hence why the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Here I am using TypeScript, if you are using Javascript, please edit code as needed.

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import googleTrendsApi from "google-trends-api";

type Data = {
  name: string
}

export default function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {
  const data = googleTrendsApi
    .interestOverTime({ keyword: ["Women's march", "Trump Inauguration"] })
    .then(function (results: any) {
      res.status(200).json(results)
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just out of interest what library are you using for charting if you are?

Comment: Creating a chart? There are a lot of libraries out there, but I think using [react-chartjs](https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2) would be good.